# pyenv doctor fail to see/solve gnureadline and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyenv

```
$ pyenv doctor
Cloning /home/andre/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-doctor/bin/.....
Installing python-pyenv-doctor...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 21.04 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20210530203727.11673
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20210530203727.11673.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for rl_gnu_readline_p in -lreadline... no
configure: error: GNU readline is not installed.
Problem(s) detected while checking system.

See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems for known solutions.
andre@loke:~$ pip install gnureadline
Requirement already satisfied: gnureadline in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (8.0.0)
andre@loke:~$ pip3 install gnureadline
Requirement already satisfied: gnureadline in ./.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages (8.0.0)

$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.2 (set by /home/andre/.pyenv/version)
```

This is actually my attempt to troubleshoot tkinter (`apt install python3-tk` is done.)
I have no clue as to how it got broken, it worked fine before.

> ```
> $ python -m tkinter
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/andre/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
>     mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
>   File "/home/andre/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
>     return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
>   File "/home/andre/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
>     __import__(pkg_name)
>   File "/home/andre/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py",
> ```
>
> line 37, in 
> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

How can I clean up this mess?

Comment: Hi André: any new info on this ? I have the exact same error on `pyenv local 3.7.1; python -m pip spacy ; python -m spacy ...`.  for other local versions of Python (e.g. 3.9.0), I have no error. Tx.